# Plot quartiles of data series in a matplotlib chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to illustrate the quartiles of a distribution sample with matplotlib. It is probably best explained by an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

x = sorted([random.randrange(0,n) for n in range(1,1000)])
median_y = np.median(x)
median_x = x.index(median)

plt.plot(x)
plt.plot((median_x,median_x), (0,median_y),'k:')
plt.plot((0,median_x), (median_y,median_y),'k:')
```

[image: output]

Do you see a more convenient way to add quartiles 1,2 (median), and 3 than my clumsy solution? I could not find any command to plot a point with helper lines like this. And how could I add numbers to the points or axes?

Comment: [`vlines` and `hlines`](http://matplotlib.org/dev/examples/pylab_examples/vline_hline_demo.html) might be a bit more appropriate for drawing the horizontal and vertical lines...